# Module '"@azure/msal-angular"' has no exported member 'MSAL_CONFIG'

Tags: angular, typescript, msal-angular

I have an Angular 11 project where I'm trying to import MSAL_CONFIG in app.module, but I only get the error above.

```
import { MsalBroadcastService, MSAL_CONFIG, MsalGuard, MsalGuardConfiguration, MsalInterceptor, MsalInterceptorConfiguration, MsalModule,
```

All the other classes are imported correctly. Why is this?

In package.jxon I'm using "@azure/msal-angular": "^2.0.0",
"@azure/msal-browser": "^2.16.1",

Answer (score 1):

Remove all `MSAL_CONFIG` References from your app.module.ts
And add the guard and/or interceptor configs if you need them (MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG and MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG). This is a good example for angular 11 using their documentation. https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/samples/msal-angular-v2-samples/angular11-sample-app/src/app/app.module.ts

Edit: most recent angular 15 example link.
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/samples/msal-angular-v3-samples/angular15-sample-app/src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: it's gone chief

Comment: Updated with angular 15 sample links